# Python: How to redirect print output to txt file?

Tags: python

I have Print function which looks like this: `print(*hint_y, sep='\n')` (hint_y is nested list), which output looks like this:

```
      1    
    1 1 1  
  4 1 1 1 4
```

How can i redirect this print to text file?

Comment: Instead of redirecting, just write it to a file using `with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:f.write(*hint_y)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by using providing file proxy in the file parameter of print function.

For example,

```
f = open('temp.txt' , 'w')
print('a' , file = f)
f.close()
```

Here,I redirected string 'a' in the file 'temp.txt'.

Answer (score 0):

Like Sanchit.Jain's answer, but uses a with statement to close the file automatically:

```
with open('temp.txt' , 'w') as f:
    print('a' , file=f)
```